# Is it possible to populate the quickfix list with files based on criteria that are independent of the files content?

Tags: quickfix, vimgrep

I am interested in populating the quickfix list with filenames selected according to a criteria that is independent of the files content.
For example, I want to populate the quickfix only with python files present in the current directory and its subdirectories, independently of the files content.

I tried `:vimgrep// ./**/*.py` but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble with:

```
:vimgrep // ./**/*.py
```

is that it will search for the last search pattern, that's what `//` does, so you can basically get two unsatisfactory outcomes:

- there is nothing in register `/`, therefore you get an error,
- there is something in register `/`, therefore you *possibly* get a quickfixlist, with *possibly* one entry for *possibly* every desired file.

That is a pretty haphazard strategy.

One way to make it more deterministic while keeping it lo-tech would be to use a more precise pattern that is sure to be found exactly *once*, in *every single matching file*:

```
:vimgrep /\%1l/ **/*.py
```

where we search for line 1, which is guaranteed to be found even in empty files.

See `:help \%l`.

Another lo-tech approach could be to do something like:

```
set efm=%f
:cexpr glob('**/*.py')
set efm&
```

where we:

- temporarily change the `:help 'errorformat'` option so that it can deal with a list of files,
- use `:help :cexpr` to populate the quickfix list with the output of `:help glob()`, parsed according to the `errorformat` option,
- revert `errorformat` to its default value.

But that assumes that `errorformat` was the default value to begin with.

One could also probably do something similar with `$ man find` or `$ man locate`. Or possibly with a combination of `:help setqflist()` and `glob()`, etc.

But I think the `\%1l` trick is the easiest to pull "on the spot": just basic vimming without any setup or third-party cruft.

[image: vim]

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
:vimgrep /\%^/ **/*.py
```

Where `\%^` match the beginning of a file.